# Why area of rectangle is less than its integral

Tags: calculus

Let us suppose we have a triangle with base $j$ to $j-1$ and height of $1/j$ for $j=2,...,n$. Then,

$$\frac{1}{j}(j-(j-1))\lt\int_{j-1}^{j}\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Why $\frac{1}{j}(j-(j-1))\lt\int_{j-1}^{j}\frac{1}{x}dx$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams. Thank you, but in his question it's $f(a)$ is larger, but here it's smaller?

Comment: Right but it's almost the exact same idea. You should be able to piece it together from the answers therein.